# Angular provider returning an array

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a `customRoutesProvider`, but when I ask for `customerRoutes` in a controller, the array is always empty...

```
angular.module('introToAngularApp')
    .config(function(customRoutesProvider) {
        customRoutesProvider.setRoutes([ /* routes */ ])
    });
    .provider('customRoutes', function() {
        this.customRoutes = [];

        this.setRoutes = function (routes) {
            this.customRoutes = routes;
        };

        this.getRoutes = function() {
            return customRoutes;
        };

        // Method for instantiating
        this.$get = function() {
            var customRoutes = this.customRoutes;

            return {
                getRoutes: function() {
                    return customRoutes;
                }
            };
        };
    })
    .controller('DemoCtrl', function(customRoutes) {
        console.log(customRoutes.getRoutes()); // []
    });
```

I've even tried to push individual routes into `this.customRoutes` instead of just assigning it.

Anybody have a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you replicate it in a small example. It seems working fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/zYBzdK?p=preview

Comment: Guess the typo in the posted code `;` is accidental while posting right. Also provider is defined before config block correct in your real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `this` inside `$this.get`-`getRoutes` is different from its parent.
You need to access as not `this`, but `that`,`_this`, or whatever

```
.provider('customRoutes', function() {
    this.customRoutes = [];

    this.setRoutes = function (routes) {
        this.customRoutes = routes;
    };

    this.getRoutes = function() {
        return customRoutes;
    };

    // Method for instantiating
    var _this = this;
    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            getRoutes: function() {
                return _this.customRoutes;
            }
        };
    };
})
```

plnkr here, http://plnkr.co/edit/YlcYAMp1lHfJ0RaFHlFQ?p=preview